# Equivalent SQL Server's Backup COPY ONLY in DB2

Tags: backup, db2, restore, recovery

In, DB2 when you have a recovery strategie, you have a Full backup, then some deltas or incrementals in between. They are creating based on the previous full (first delta, or any incre.

```
-F---D---D---I---D---D---D
```

However, if you perform a backup in the middle (let's suppose for a test, and the file will be deleted), then the following deltas or incrementals will be created based of that backup that was not part of the recovery strategie.

```
-F-
  F--D---D---I---D---D---D
```

I saw that SQL Server has an option calle COPY ONLY that prevents this problem: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx

How can I do that in DB2?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do that with DB2. Deltas and Incrementals will be based off of the last full backup taken (either offline or online). If anything it would cause one to adjust your recovery strategy for that week.

If you needed the data however, why not just copy the backups you need (the full and any deltas/incrementals) and restore those elsewhere, rather than taking a full backup? Or use `db2look` and `db2move` to extract the data for test purposes?

Otherwise I know IBM does have a product called IBM DB2 Advanced Recovery Feature (it was formerly an Optim product if I remember right). It has a subcomponent called  IBM DB2 Merge Backup for Linux, UNIX and Windows that allows you to combine the full backup with subsequent deltas and incrementals to create a full backup to restore to. This gives you the advantage of only needing to restore one backup, rather than progressing through the deltas and incrementals.

Comment: Well, db2move + db2look is a very difficult solution (store procedure order, data load before Referential integrity, etc). This is not a solution

Comment: Let's suppose you need to give a backup of the database to someone else. You are not going to give full + delta + logs, you give a full backup and that's all.

Comment: The Merge backup is a partial solution, however it shows that DB2 does not have this option of a "backup copy only". :(